# Flutter constructor from json list-string

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I cant solve my error.

> E/flutter (30343): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List'

```
class Exercise {
  int id;
  String name;
  List<int> equipmentIds;

  Exercise(this.id, this.name, this.equipmentIds);

  Exercise.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json['id'],
        name = json['name'],
        equipmentIds = json['equipmentIds'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {'id': id, 'name': name, 'equipmentIds': equipmentIds};
}
```

Comment: could you include your api response too?

Comment: can you please add the json string you receive as code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `List.from`

```dart
return Exercise(
  map['id']?.toInt() ?? 0,
  map['name'] ?? '',
  List<int>.from(map['equipmentIds']),
);
```

It would better to handle null  while reading map , can be `List<int>.from(map['equipmentIds']?? [] ),`

Comment: Worked with ```equipmentIds =  List<int>.from(json['equipmentIds']);``` 
My List is not nullable so I always just pass an empty list [].